# Flask polling app not interacting with backend when vote

Tags: python, flask, polling, pusher-js

I am working on a side project looking to create a polling app with flask where the admin can input images and then the user will vote on the randomly scrambled images. I am following along with the link below to try and cater the app to my own needs-
https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-poll-python/#communicating-with-the-backend.

*I took out my pusher secret key for confidentiality

Everything runs fine accept when i get to the polling page, i click to vote and there is no interaction, i have tried to put the /vote route in the /polling route seeing if maybe it never gets called being out of the function however i did not get any success.

I have attached my app.py and my app.js file, however if need be i can publish my repository to be public on github if that would be helpful. In addition my pusher account had a connection to the app but i am unsure if this connection is still valid.  my app.py file is as follows-

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request,flash,redirect,url_for
import os
import sqlite3, json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
from pusher import Pusher
from sqlite3 import Error

import simplejson

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="123"

pusher = Pusher(
    app_id='1580504',
    key='7967ce0fbdf40980ed5f',
    secret='',
    cluster='us2',
    ssl=True)


con=sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
con.execute("create table if not exists image(pid integer primary key,img TEXT,Team TEXT)")
global cur
cur = con.cursor()
con.close()

app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']="static\images"

@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    con = sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from image")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    con.close()

    if request.method=='POST':
        upload_image=request.files['upload_image']
        Team = request.form.get('Team')
        if upload_image.filename!='':
            filepath=os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],upload_image.filename)
            upload_image.save(filepath)
            con=sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("insert into image(img, Team)values(?, ?)",(upload_image.filename, Team, ))
        
            con.commit()
            flash("File Upload Successfully","success")

            con = sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
            con.row_factory=sqlite3.Row
            cur=con.cursor()
            cur.execute("select * from image")
            data=cur.fetchall()
            con.close()
            return render_template("upload.html",data=data)
    return render_template("upload.html",data=data)

@app.route('/admin')
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')

@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/polling")
def polling():
    con = sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from image")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    
    #data = [random.choice(data) for _ in range(4)]

    data = random.sample(data, 4)
    return render_template('next_page.html', data = data)

def main():
    global con, cur

def update_item(cur, item):
    sql = '''UPDATE items
            SET votes = votes + 1
            WHERE name = ? '''
    cur.execute(sql, item)

def select_all_items(cur, name):
    sql = ''' SELECT * FROM items '''
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    rows.append({'name' : name})
    return json.dumps(rows)

@app.route('/vote', methods=['POST'])
def vote():
    data = simplejson.loads(request.data)
    update_item(cur, [data['member']])
    output = select_all_items(cur, [data['member']])
    pusher.trigger(u'poll', u'vote', output)
    return request.data

@app.route('/delete_record/<string:id>')
def delete_record(id):
    try:
        con=sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
        cur=con.cursor()
        cur.execute("delete from image where pid=?",[id])
        con.commit()
        flash("Record Deleted Successfully","success")
    except:
        flash("Record Deleted Failed", "danger")
    finally:
        return redirect(url_for("upload"))
        con.close()



@app.route("/next_page")
def next_page():
    con = sqlite3.connect("myimage.db")
    con.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from image")
    data = cur.fetchall()
    
    #data = [random.choice(data) for _ in range(4)]

    data = random.sample(data, 4)

    return render_template('next_page.html', data = data)

'''@app.route("/test")
def test():
    return render_template('test.html')'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My app.js file is as follows-

```js
var pollMembers = document.querySelectorAll('.poll-member')
    
var members = [ res.Team ]


pollMembers.forEach((pollMember, index) => {
  pollMember.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    handlePoll(members[index])
  }, true)
})


var handlePoll = function(member) {
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/vote', {member}).then((r) => console.log(r))
}


const pusher = new Pusher('7967ce0fbdf40980ed5f', {
  cluster: 'us2',
  encrypted: true
});


var channel = pusher.subscribe('poll');


channel.bind('vote', function(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < (data.length - 1); i++) { 
    var total = data[0].votes + data[1].votes + data[2].votes + data[3].votes
    document.getElementById(data[i].Team).style.width = calculatePercentage(total, data[i].votes)
    document.getElementById(data[i].Team).style.background = "#388e3c" 
  }
});

let calculatePercentage = function(total, amount) {
  return (amount / total) * 100 + "%"
}
```